# apt-get not found when using Gitlab CI with runner

Tags: image, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Before starting, I want to say that current setup was working until about one or two months ago. Basically the last stage of my Gitlab CI fails and says that `apt-get` is not found.

Here is the error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.0.0 (6946bae7)
   on findar-runner ckfMigBJ
Using Shell executor...
00:00
Running on DESKTOP-VR2QRNO...
00:01
Fetching changes...
00:04
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in D:/GitLab-Runner/builds/ckfMigBJ/0/findar/findar-api/.git/
 Checking out c480b6e3 as master...
 Removing node_modules/
 git-lfs/2.7.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.2; git 08a08ae0)
 Skipping Git submodules setup
$ apt-get update -qy
00:01
 apt-get : Le terme �apt-get� n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, fonction, fichier de script ou 
 programme ex�cutable. V�rifiez l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'acc�s existe, v�rifiez que le chemin d'acc�s 
 est correct et r�essayez.
 Au caract�re C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script509642043\script.ps1:197 : 1
 + apt-get update -qy
 + ~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (apt-get:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  
 Job succeeded
```

The French error message basically means that the term `apt-get` is not recognized/known.
And I don't understand why. Here is my current `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - ver
  - init
  - tests
  - deploy

ver:
  stage: ver
  script:
    - node --version
    - whoami

init:
  stage: init
  script:
    - npm cache verify

testing:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm install -g mocha
    - echo $NODE_ENV
    - npm test

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    NODE_ENV: "dev"
  image: ruby:latest
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    - echo "Deployed to staging server"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: **censored**
  only:
    - master
```

Any idea what it could be? Thanks!

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script509642043\script.ps1:197` looks like it's trying to run apt-get on a windows machine and - therefore - fails to find it. The error also looks very powershell like.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson How come it has been working like that for a few months then? :( Any ideas how to fix. Been searching and trying stuff for a while now.

Comment: I still haven't found a way to fix this. Struggling...

Comment: have you found the solution?  because I have the same error with the command `docker`

Comment: Not really @diego but I realized the issue was on my runner. Since I was kinda running out of time, I deactivated the use of my runner and used Gitlab shared runners instead.